# Pandas function to convert a column (10,000 - 15,000) to either 2 separate columns or take the average value

Tags: pandas, dataframe

This is the table I have extracted from the PDF. I want a column with either the average or split that into 2 separate columns.

Dataframe:

[image: dataframe]

Answer (score 0):

how about this ?

```
df['Amount'].str.split('-', 1, expand=True)
```